# For Events $A$ and $B$, $A \subseteq B$ is equivalent to $A$ implies $B$? Seeking Clarification.

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

In my probability class, I was told that, if $A$ and $B$ are events, then $A \subseteq B$ is equivalent to $A$ implies $B$. So in other words, if the event A occurs, then this implies that the event B occurs, right?

However, this claim was not justified, and I'm unsure as to how it is true. It seems to me that, If an event $A$ is a subset of an event $B$, then that does not necessarily imply $B$, since the event $B$ may have other outcomes in it. Indeed, it would seem to me that the *converse* would be true? In other words, the event $B$ occurring would imply that the event $A$ occurred? This is because, since all of the element in $A$ are also in $B$, then if $B$ occurs, then all of the outcomes that make up $A$ must also have occurred?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please help me understand this.

Comment: This looks like one of those situations where careful language could have avoided a problem. Since "implies" makes sense only between two statements, whereas $\subseteq$ makes sense only between two sets, what you were told (first sentence of the question) doesn't make sense. It should be "$A\subseteq B$ is equivalent to 'the outcome is in $A$' implies 'the outcome is in $B$'." The mention of the singular "outcome" would probably have avoided the need for an explanation that only one oucome occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly, we are conducting an experiment. Before doing it, we set up a sample space, consisting of all possible outcomes of the experiment. Then, sets whose elements are these outcomes, are called events. Once the experiment has been conducted, *exactly one* of the outcomes occurs. We say that the event $A$ occurs if the outcome was in $A$. Now, let us look at your question.

If the event $A$ is a subset of the event $B$, then when $A$ occurs, one of the elements in $A$ is the outcome  of the experiment. But everything that is in $A$, is also in $B$, so that same outcome is in $B$, and hence $B$ has occurred.

On the other hand,

If $B$ occurs, then some element of $B$ is the outcome of the experiment. But, not every element of $B$ is an element of $A$, so it is possible that the outcome of the experiment may not be an element of $A$. Hence, $B$ may have occurred, but not $A$.

Key point, and flaw in your argument : if an event occurs, it does not mean *all the outcomes* in it also occur. It means, that *the single outcome which did occur* is in $A$.

EDIT : If you need clarification on what  the word "outcome" means, and how on Earth an experiment has only a single outcome  but that leads to many events occurring, do not hesitate to ask. I will illustrate with examples, because it is a confusing point.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate clarification. So, in order for an event to occur, we do not necessarily require every outcome in the event to have occurred from the experiment, but, rather, it is only necessary that a single outcome in the event occurred from the experiment?

Comment: At the end of an experiment, *exactly one outcome* occurs. The events which contain that outcome, are said to have occurred. So there is no possibility, at all, of *every outcome* to occur from an event. For example, if you are rolling  dice and your event is $\{2,5\}$, then of course the dice cannot show both $2$ and $5$ at once, right?

Comment: Ahh, this, of course, makes sense. I see what my misunderstanding was now. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: You are welcome! At any point, if you encounter further sticky situations with outcomes and events, you can return here. For now, $+1$ to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's work on an example to simplify the discussion.  Let $B$ be the event that a single die comes less or equal to 5.  Let $A$ the event that the outcome is an odd number.  Clearly  $A \subseteq B$, and $A$ implies $B$.